# Unix return status for system (echo..) suspected

Tags: perl

We have a job that runs a Perl script which prepares 3 files (Header, content, Footer) and later-on merges them into one file.

Header file preparation using system command

```
$ret = system("/usr/bin/echo '$hdr' > $HDR_FILE");
if ( $ret != 0 )
{
   print STDERR "**ERROR** error preparing header\n";
}
```

Merger File command is as below

```
  $ret = system("/usr/bin/cat $HDR_FILE $CONTENT_FILE $TRLR_FIL > $OUTPUT_FILE");
    if ( $ret != 0 )
    print STDERR "**ERROR** merge failed\n";
```

During the latest execution of the job we don't see any traces of the header errors but still final output file `$OUTPUT_FILE` did not have the header while content and trailers were present.
can

```
$ret = system("/usr/bin/echo '$hdr' > $HDR_FILE");
```

return '0' status even when the header file was empty?

Comment: This is not likely relevant to your issue, but please include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.

Comment: I can't help but feel that shell scripts should be written in shell, and Perl scripts should usually avoid using `system`, especially for sets of operations like the ones shown.  There really isn't enough information for us to be able to debug the problem.  We can't see what the various variables are set to.  Clearly, what you've posted is not verbatim from your running script because there are syntax errors (the `if` in the 'merger file' bit is incorrect, if you think about it).

Comment: Was the file empty, or did it contain just a newline?  If it contained just a newline, then `$hdr` in the Perl script didn't contain anything.  The succinct answer to your question is "Yes; `system()` could return 0 even if the header file was empty".  It would only fail if it failed to invoke the shell, or the shell failed to create the file for the I/O redirection.

Comment: $hdr is derived from certain inputs , and the logs for that run shows that all the required inputs were available for $hdr, yet some-how dint get into $HDR_FILE.

Comment: and when we re-run the job again immediately, we had the header this time correctly in the final output file , hence the wondering if something could have happened in `$ret = system("/usr/bin/echo '$hdr' > $HDR_FILE");`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : agree with your comment that , it's not a good practise to mix shell and perl , but this is some legacy code that we just maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify your code with better error handling:

Option 1: Use backtick

```
$ret = `/usr/bin/echo '$hdr' > $HDR_FILE 2>&1`;
if ( $? || $ret )
{
   print STDERR "**ERROR** error preparing header, error: $ret\n";
}
```

Option 2: Use print instead of echo

```
open(my $fh,'>',$HDR_FILE) or die "Cannot write to $HDR_FILE";
print $fh $hdr;
close($fh);
```